# Speeding up matrix multiplication in rust

Tags: rust

I've been recently trying to speed up the following piece of source

```
                let mut j_offset: usize = 0;
                for j in 0..self.object_count {
                    let mut tmp_sum: f32 = self.storage.get_unchecked(some_offset + j).sub_object;
                    for i in 0..self.some_counter {
                        tmp_sum += input_obj.get_unchecked(i)
                            * self.storage.get_unchecked(i + j_offset as usize).sub_object;
                    }
                    j_offset += self.some_counter;
                    *output_obj.get_unchecked_mut(j) = tmp_sum;
                }
```

It feels like this multiplication can be made much faster (in native/nightly Rust), however I'm missing some intuition about what are the main bottlenecks here. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Likely not going to result in remarkable speed ups, but using `get_unchecked` can [actually be slower](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/gl5scx/get_unchecked_makes_things_slower/). Did you profile before you wen unsafe?

Comment: Please post reproducible code.

Comment: @JaredSmith good point - yes, it's around 20% slower if not using get_unchecked. Chayim, will try to create one, it was more about if I missed some general pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar thing not long ago, few obvious things:

1. Make sure you've set optimisation level/mode to **release**
2. Write a good benchmark test with multiplications of **different magnitude**. Like 10x10, 100x100, etc.. Depending on the algorithm this will drastically change the performance. One algorithm may be better on big matrices than the other one. Also providing a minimal benchmark as part of the question would be great.
3. Look into **Strassen algorithm**. Although as of late 2022 there should be new emerging algorithms.
   See https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-05172-4
4. Look up to existing Rust crates, i've personally used the Rust **NDArray** with **OpenBLAS**. From what i've observed the performance gain was incomparable. If you are curious about usage look into my repo : https://github.com/MPopovych/Neurotick/blob/main/neurotick/src/matrix/nmatrix.rs